# Unable to extend Base field in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is how I try to extend `Ext.form.field.Base`:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.CKEditorInline', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    alias: 'widget.ckeditorinline',
    requires: [
        'Ext.XTemplate'
    ],
    constructor: function(config) {
        Ext.applyIf(config, {
        fieldSubTpl: [
        '<div id="{id}-editor" contenteditable="true" class="ckeditorinline"></div><input id="{id}" name="{name}" type="text" value="{value}" style="display:none"/>',
        { compiled: true }]
        });
        this.callParent([config]);
    },
    getValue: function () {
        var el = document.getElementById(this.id + "-inputEl-editor");
        if (!!el) {
            return el.innerHTML;
        }
        return null;
    },
    setValue: function (value) {
        var el = document.getElementById(this.id + "-inputEl-editor");
        if (value === "") value = "<p><br/></p>";
        if (!!el) {
            el.innerHTML = !!value ? value : "<p><br/></p>";
        }
    },
    reset: function () {
        var el = document.getElementById(this.id + "-inputEl-editor");
        if (!!el) {
            el.innerHTML = '<p><br/></p>';
        }
    }
});
```

So, basically what I want is to use editable div instead of an input field. However, when I try to type (print) something inside this field, I see that I can not print a space character or make a break with Enter (so, such values as "one two" or "one\ntwo" are not possible and instead I get "onetwo"). What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by unable? Are you getting any error or is compilation successful but nor working ?

Comment: Compilation is successful, but as I said I have problems when trying to print some values in my contenteditable div element, created with a template.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the whitespace to `&nbsp;` and change the carriage returns to `<br/>`.  You could try:

```
setValue: function (value) {
    var el = document.getElementById(this.id + "-inputEl-editor");
    if (value === "") value = "<p><br/></p>";
    value = value.replace(/\n/, "<br/>");
    value = value.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;");
    if (!!el) {
        el.innerHTML = !!value ? value : "<p><br/></p>";
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it tomorrow!